# Python Insert values one-by-one through looping in an array

Tags: python, arrays, loops

**[UPDATED: Fixed some mistakes on the PHP and Python code]**

I have a simple request. In PHP, I can declare which index will a value be inserted by simply writing like this `$sample[10] = "Sample"`. To insert multiple values, I would create a for loop where in each loop a value will be inserted in the array. Written below is a sample of that code but with a few alterations as I based the looping with the splitted string array's length :

```
$toexp = str_split("Hello World");
$array = array();
for ($x = 0; $x < count($toexp); $x++){
    $array[$x] = $toexp[$x]; //sample value only
    echo $array[$x];
}
```

I attempted to create a similar code in Python

```
samplearray = []
splits = list("Hello World")
for p in splits:
    samplearray.extend(p)
    print(samplearray[1])
```

However, an error pops up:

```
print(samplearray[1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Does this mean the value only inserts at index 0? If I print samplearray[0] no error occurs and it prints out the value in that index. Please explain to me how I can replicate the code from PHP to Python. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Let's [ignore PHP](https://xyproblem.info/) for the moment. What are you trying to do? Insert elements at arbitrary positions in an array? Append items to an array?

Comment: On your first iteration you don't have anything at index 1. You want `print(samplearray[x])`.

Comment: @jarmod Insert elements at aribitrary positions. I'm sorry I forgot to add that I do not know how to achieve this in PHP so I simple tried extend()

Comment: There is many errors in your PHP code. 1st : explode always take two params. 2nd : `$array = ();` does not means nothing, you should write `$array = array();` instead. 3rd: forgot a semi-colon at the end of line 7.

Comment: @Aaron_Actu I'm sorry for those mistakes. I just wrote a code from the back of my mind. Should've tested it first but anyways. I'll just update it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`extend` extends an array from an iterator, which is **not** what you want in this case. Unlike PHP, Python does not allow you to insert at arbitrary elements in an array past the end. However, since you're always inserting at the end of the array, you can just use the `append` method to add an extra element:

```py
samplearray = []
x = 0
for p in "Hello world":
    samplearray.append(x + 1)
    print(samplearray[x])
    x += 1
```

Comment: But How do I insert each split of "Hello world" in the array? Would it be something like this: samplearray.append(p)

Comment: Yes it would be.